# Value in a hidden input is not passed to controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pass the user ID through an Ajax call, but it is coming empty. 
I feel the value="{{ $user->id }}" in the input tag is incorrect, but I'm not sure.

The following is my input tag :

```
<div>   
<input type = "hidden" name = "id" value="{{ $user->id }}">
</div>
```

The following is my ajax code :

```
$('#grp-save').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: urlGrp,
            data: {uid: $('#id').val(), _token: token}
        })

    .done(function () {

            $('#join-req').modal('hide');
        });
});
```

The following is my controller :

```
public function jmGroup(Request $request)
    {

               $u_id = $request['uid'];

                      $grpusr = new Grpusr();
                      $grpusr->user_id = $u_id;
                       $grpusr->save();


                    return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: from where you request input 'uid'?

Comment: You're trying to access the input by its `Id` on `$('#id').val()` but you didn't specify `Id` attribute, just `name`. either specify `id="id"` on your input (btw I would suggest a less generic name for that identifier), or change the jquery to `$('[name=id]')`

Comment: Also, this is 2019, we don't use jquery anymore by default. I hope this is some kind of legacy code

Comment: @PabloRecalde, what is the alternative of Jquery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to defined the id parameter for your hidden input field, because that is what you are referencing in your JS Code.

```
<input type = "hidden" id="id" name = "id" value="{{ $user->id }}">
```

```
$('#id').val()
```

Here Jquery is basically looking for a element having id as id.  You should give it a more meaningful name like userId because a document can not have more than 1 element with same id

Answer (score 2):

You don't have `id` on your field, so either add this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="{{ $user->id }}">
```

or use this instead:

```
$('input[name=id]').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to select the value of a field with an id named id:

```
$('#id').val()
```

However your input field does not contain an id attribute:

```
<div>   
<input type = "hidden" name = "id" value="{{ $user->id }}">
</div>
```

Adding `id="id"` should fix it.

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "id" id="id" value="{{ $user->id }}">
```